Strange variable scope behavior when calling function recursivly
EDIT: sorry. this is my first question here.
Here is a minimal working example
#!/bin/bash
#
count=0

function something() {
    if test -f "$1"; then
        # is a file
        ((count++))
        echo $count $1
    elif test -d "$1"; then
        # is a folder
        find $1 | while read line; do
            if [ $1 != $line ]; then  # first line in find is the folder itself. prevent infinte recursion
                something $line
            fi
        done
    fi
}

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    something "$1"
    shift
done

echo "Processed $count files"

Example output:
$ ./test.sh *
1 0/file1.txt
2 0/file2.txt
1 1/file1.txt
2 1/file2.txt
1 2/file1.txt
2 2/file2.txt
1 3/file1.txt
2 3/file2.txt
1 4/file1.txt
2 4/file2.txt
1 5/file1.txt
2 5/file2.txt
1 6/file1.txt
2 6/file2.txt
1 7/file1.txt
2 7/file2.txt
1 8/file1.txt
2 8/file2.txt
1 9/file1.txt
2 9/file2.txt
1 test.sh
Processed 1 files

As you can see each time I call the function recursively it returns to the variable state on parent function and messes up the count.
Using Ubuntu 22.06 on WSL2 VM

This is obviously not your real code. Do you use local anywhere? Or declare inside a function? If not, then the variable is global. No there is no separate global scope.

I agree with glenn.  This is confusing.   (1) What does unpack have to do with A and B?   (2) What do the command-line parameters have to do with anything?  Do they affect the control flow?   (3) It’s hard to debug “sometimes”.  Can you clarify?   (4) For a given scenario, is the result consistent?   (5) Can you give a runnable example that demonstrates the problem (perhaps including tests on "$1" that determine whether A calls itself or B)? … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  (6) Suggestion: change your echo statements to echo "A: $count" and echo "outside: $count".  Add echo "B: $count", echo "Calling A with arg xxx" and echo "Calling B" in the appropriate places.

Sorry. Done. Had to try a few times to reproduce

Copy/paste your script into https://www.shellcheck.net/ and it'll tell you of some additional issues you need to fix.

Do I get it right that you want to count all files in a directory tree, or something like that? I.e. you want the variable count to be global?
Your issue is here:
find $1 | while read line; do

See that pipeline? What pipelines do is that they start two or more processes in parallel, and doing that requires starting distinct OS-level processes. Which the shell does here by cloning itself. Those clones can't affect the parent process, so the variable is effectively localized, and when the pipeline ends, you get the original value back.
See Why is my variable local in one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop? for solutions to that.
As an example, a normal recursive function:
% cat local1.sh
#!/bin/bash

count=1
func() {
    (( count++ ))
    printf "$1 %$1s count=$count\n" ""
    if (( $1 < 3 )); then
        func $(( $1 + 1 ))
    fi
    printf "$1 %$1s count=$count\n" ""
}

func 1

running that prints:
1   count=2
2    count=3
3     count=4
3     count=4
2    count=4
1   count=4

Now, change the inner func line to e.g. echo | func $(( $1 + 1 )) and you'll see the count go back down when the function calls return.

Now, another thing entirely is that calling find on each level of a recursive tree walk is a bit suspicious, since find will itself recursively walk the whole tree. Are you sure you want to add another walk on top of that? It'll lead to directories being processed multiple times.
If we go back to counting files, you could do that with just one find, e.g.:
find "$dir" -type f | wc -l

though that would count filenames with newlines as multiple files. With GNU find, you could use ... -printf x | wc -c to avoid that.

Actually, just removing the manual recursion should be all right to call a function for each (regular) file:
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s lastpipe

count=0
func() {
    echo "processing '$1'..."
    ((count++))
}
find "$1" -type f | while IFS= read -r file; do
    func "$file"
done
echo "end. count=$count"

Clear IFS and use read -r as above to avoid having read treat whitespace and backslashes specially.
(and to avoid issues with newlines in filenames, use find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do ... in Bash))

Thank you for you answer!
I don't want just to count, in my original script I must check the mime type (file --mime-type) to decide what to do regardless of the file name. I actually want to decompress all archives. So I must iterate through all files.
I definitly agree it is not efficient. It's actually another subject. I just want to know if I could use my method without loosing my count

@ShlomoV, I was more worried about correctness than efficiency. Anyway, wouldn't it do to just run find once and loop over the output? (see edit)

yes but I need to have an option to iterate over files OR traverse through folders too, but yes, you make sense.
Regarding my question, according to the link you gave me
The answer would be, replacing:
find $1 | while read line; do... done
with
while read line; do... done < <(find $1)

@ShlomoV I suggest you post a new question, explaining what you want the script to do and showing what you have so far. If we know the real objective, we could probably help you find a more efficient way to achieve it.

@ShlomoV, either process substitution or shopt -s lastpipe. You can add more conditions to find to control what dirs it walks, but if the condition is something that's not easy to do there, that does make it a bit awkward. Now find could run a shell or something for each file it processes and you could use those as conditions too, but that's also something that might start looking a bit hairy. But like terdon says, it'd be easier to say something if we knew more about the conditions you need in the tree walk.

Thanks. It's an assignment I got for enrolling to a course. I will obviously make my scripts more efficient, the task was just to show you can handle the assignment. I got stuck just with this issue which I couldn't find any resolution for. After enrolling I will be glad to hear a more efficient approach...

The "How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)" FAQ suggests while IFS= read -r file; do func "$file" done < <(find "$1" -type f)) instead of find "$1" -type f | while IFS= read -r file; do func "$file" done to avoid that subshell too.

@EdMorton, doh, silly me, I tried to be simpler there, but of course that has the same issue with the subshell when the loop ends... Actually, I think pipes look better than <(), so perhaps lastpipe would do...

another possibilité to not use a pipe:   mkfifo /tmp/a_pipe ; find ... > /tmp/a_pipe & while read line; do ... ; done < /tmp/a_pipe ; command rm /tmp/a_pipe : no subshells needed.
